# Plugin for email fetching in a grails application

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am using grails 2.x. I am looking for a plugin or any reocmmendation. I need to cover functionality to fetch emails from email providers (e.g. gmail, ...).
After fetching the mail I look into my database if I know the senders email address. If yes I save the email in my database. If no a skip the message.

So far I only found plugins used for sending out emails but not for fetching emails.

Is there any code (plugin, or pure java code) I could reuse for this request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any plugin available but using [JavaMail](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/) is pretty simple. Here is a quick example of fetching messages from an inbox from a POP3 server:

```
import javax.mail.*
import javax.mail.internet.*

String popHost = "mail.wherever.com"
String popUsername ="someone@wherever.com"
String popPassword = "password123"

Properties properties = new Properties()

properties.put("mail.pop3.host", popHost)
properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995")
properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true")
Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties)

// create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s")
store.connect(popHost, popUsername, popPassword)

// create the folder object and open it
Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX")
emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE)

// retrieve the messages from the folder in an array
Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages()
log.debug("${messages.length} messages found to process")

messages.each { message ->
    log.debug("Processing e-mail message")
    log.debug("Subject: " + message.getSubject())
    log.debug("From: " + message.getFrom()[0])
}
```

This is just a simple example, may contain typos and such since I wrote it off the top of my head. Assuming you're using Groovy and inside a Grails Service.

**Note:** This example assumes the use of SSL and port of 995. This is true for such providers as gmail, but not all.

Comment: Using the same code comments as in this example? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_deleting_emails.htm

Comment: Wow now that's terrifying that it's almost identical. o.O Guess I know where I got the other snippet (where I lifted it from, spring batch job) from originally. Want to copy the example to your answer and I'll delete mine?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably no mail reading plugin (at least I couldn't find one). As such I'd recommend using JavaMail API directly. An example of accessing a POP3 mailbox can be seen [here](http://alvinalexander.com/java/javamail-pop-pop3-reader-email-inbox-example).

Documentation is locate [here](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/).